# Why this proof is incorrect?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I have an exercise that I cannot really understand:

> Let $P(n)$ be a property over the naturals (i.e., $n \in N$). The induction
>   axiom, taking $0$ for the base-case instance, is the formula:

$$[P (0) \land (\forall k \in \mathbb{N} P(k) \rightarrow P(k + 1))] \rightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{N} P(n)$$

> Take some time to understand clearly what this formula tells you. Then
>   consider the following . I ask a friend of mine to select a sequence
>   of numbers, starting with an odd one. I want to prove that all the
>   numbers my friend will select will be odd.
>
> - Base case:
>
>   my friend selects the first number, that has to be odd. $P(1)$ holds
>     trivially.
> - Induction step:
>
>   assume $P(n)$ holds for an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$: consider the sequence $\{s_1, \dots , s_{n+1}\}$ of the selected numbers, $n + 1$ too. Split the sequence
>     in two parts: $S_1 = \{s_1\}$ and $S_2 = \{s_2, \dots , s_{n+1}\}$. We know that $P(1)$ holds therefore $S_1$ contains an odd number. Moreover, since we
>     assumed that $P(n)$ holds for any arbitrary $n$, the sequence $S_n$ (with $n$
>     elements) contains only odd numbers. The union of the two sequences of
>     odd numbers is a sequence of odd numbers, so the sequence $\{s_1, \dots ,s_{n+1}\}$ contains only odd numbers, proving that $P (n + 1)$ holds. This
>     concludes the proof:we showed by induction that $P(n)$ holds for all $n \in\mathbb{N}^+$.

First of all, I don't understand what has the formula above to do with the proof.

Then regarding the correctness of the proof, I have some ideas:

1. The fact that base case is true (if he selects just a number, then it's an odd number), does not mean that **s1** in the first sequence is odd, right? If yes, could you explain better why?

Are there other problems in the proof (if my guess 1 is correct)?

Comment: You can disprove this via direct counterexample. I pick (1,2).

Comment: Where is $P(0)$ as a base case? Also when you use induction you *only* assume that $P(n)$ holds. Not that $P(0),\ldots,P(n)$ hold. So you cannot use $P(1)$ unless you prove it explicitly.

Comment: The invalid step is "since we assumed that P(n) holds for any arbitrary n, the sequence Sn (with n elements) contains only odd numbers".  P(n) involves *the first n numbers chosen*, not any arbitrary n-length sub-sequence of the numbers chosen.

Comment: @Benjamin: You only proved that you're not the OP's friend, since he clearly only picks odd numbers! :-)

Comment: @BenjaminRoycraft I think the idea is to identify which step in the proof is invalid (clearly the result is invalid)

Comment: It's a junk proof, perhaps trying to convince you not to give up your intuition :-) . What is $P(x)$, after all? It seems to have been replaced by a dragon that can do anything.

Comment: Ok, if you guys didn't like that answer, I pick (1,4).

Comment: No, I'm joking. The problem is that you only proved the assumption for the first part, $S_1$. The proof never establishes that every number in $S_2$ is odd, and that's the part that includes $s_{n+1}$.

Comment: The proposition only says that every number chosen up to $s_n$ is odd, it says nothing about the oddness of $s_{n+1}$. The oddness assumption is only valid for the specific sequence $\{s_1,...,s_n\}$, but the proof assumes that it must be true for $any$ sequence, just so long as it's of length $n$.

Comment: This is the standard all horses are of the same colour "proof." The $n=1$ case works, and **if** $n\ge 2$ we can deduce $P(n+1)$ from $P(n)$. But the induction step from $n=1$ to $n=2$ fails.